# How to use continue for a while loop in a nested for loop?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I am typing a typical game in console now. But I have a mistake about loops. How can I use continue keyword in for loop in while loop? I want to use it for while loop.

```
    *****while (true) {
        System.out.print("Please type a number(It must be in between 0-"+width2+") to define the row : ");
        int x = input.nextInt();
        while (x<1 || x>width) {
            System.out.print("Please type a avaliable number to define the row : ");
            x = input.nextInt();
        }

        System.out.print("Please type a number(It must be in between 0-"+length2+") to define the column : ");
        int y = input.nextInt();
        while (y<1 || y>length) {
            System.out.print("Please type a avaliable number to define the column : ");
            y = input.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println();
        
        int value = 10*x + y;
        
        
        
        
        for (int i = 0; i < x * y; i++) {
            if (value == array[i]) {
                System.out.println("Please type different values from beforehands.");
                continue;
            }
        }
        
        array[counter] = value;
        System.out.println("array["+counter+"] = "+array[counter]);
        counter++;
        if (gamingArea[x-1][y-1] == 0) {
            point+=10;
            continue;
        }else {
            System.out.println("GAME OVER! Your point is "+point+".");
            break;
        }
        
    }*****
```

Answer (score 0):

You can label the `while` statement and specify it in the `continue` statement.

```
L: while (true) {
    // A
    for (int i = 0; i < x * y; i++) {
        if (value == array[i]) {
            System.out.println("Please type different values from beforehands.");
            continue L;
        }
    }
    // 
}
```

You can also write without `continue` like this.

```
while (true) {
    // A 
    if (IntStream.range(0, x * y).anyMatch(i -> i == value)) {
        System.out.println("Please type different values from beforehands.");
    } else {
        // B
    }
}
```

You can simply remove the second `continue` statement in your code.

Comment: This method is used like using of goto? If it is that, can you type a code without goto for this game?